# Angular routes pushed to array after creation not working in production

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, development-environment, production-environment

I've created a github repository which has a perfect example of my issue.

https://github.com/rjriel/dynamic-route-example

The important part of the code in this repo is in `app.module.ts`

```
let mainRoutes: Routes = [{
  path: "first",
  component: FirstComponent
}]

mainRoutes.push({
  path: "second",
  component: SecondComponent
})

@NgModule({
...
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(mainRoutes),
```

When running this code in development (ie. `ng serve`) both routes navigate correctly. However, when running this code in production (ie. `ng serve --prod`) the `second` route that was added through `mainRoutes.push` results in the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL 
Segment: 'second'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'second'
    at t.BkNc.t.noMatchError (vendor.0828fd59ec5e6a599e72.bundle.js:1)
    at e.selector (vendor.0828fd59ec5e6a599e72.bundle.js:1)
    at e.error (vendor.0828fd59ec5e6a599e72.bundle.js:1)
    at e.T14+.e._error (vendor.0828fd59ec5e6a599e72.bundle.js:1)
    at e.T14+.e.error (vendor.0828fd59ec5e6a599e72.bundle.js:1)
    at e.T14+.e._error (vendor.0828fd59ec5e6a599e72.bundle.js:1)
    at e.T14+.e.error (vendor.0828fd59ec5e6a599e72.bundle.js:1)
    at e.T14+.e._error (vendor.0828fd59ec5e6a599e72.bundle.js:1)
    at e.T14+.e.error (vendor.0828fd59ec5e6a599e72.bundle.js:1)
    at e.T14+.e._error (vendor.0828fd59ec5e6a599e72.bundle.js:1)
    at t.BkNc.t.noMatchError (vendor.0828fd59ec5e6a599e72.bundle.js:1)
    at e.selector (vendor.0828fd59ec5e6a599e72.bundle.js:1)
    at e.error (vendor.0828fd59ec5e6a599e72.bundle.js:1)
    at e.T14+.e._error (vendor.0828fd59ec5e6a599e72.bundle.js:1)
    at e.T14+.e.error (vendor.0828fd59ec5e6a599e72.bundle.js:1)
    at e.T14+.e._error (vendor.0828fd59ec5e6a599e72.bundle.js:1)
    at e.T14+.e.error (vendor.0828fd59ec5e6a599e72.bundle.js:1)
    at e.T14+.e._error (vendor.0828fd59ec5e6a599e72.bundle.js:1)
    at e.T14+.e.error (vendor.0828fd59ec5e6a599e72.bundle.js:1)
    at e.T14+.e._error (vendor.0828fd59ec5e6a599e72.bundle.js:1)
    at u (polyfills.8c1e4b56978ce6347832.bundle.js:1)
    at u (polyfills.8c1e4b56978ce6347832.bundle.js:1)
    at polyfills.8c1e4b56978ce6347832.bundle.js:1
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.8c1e4b56978ce6347832.bundle.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.0828fd59ec5e6a599e72.bundle.js:1)
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.8c1e4b56978ce6347832.bundle.js:1)
    at r.runTask (polyfills.8c1e4b56978ce6347832.bundle.js:1)
    at o (polyfills.8c1e4b56978ce6347832.bundle.js:1)
    at t.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.8c1e4b56978ce6347832.bundle.js:1)
    at h (polyfills.8c1e4b56978ce6347832.bundle.js:1)
```

Would anybody happen to know why compiling for production would produce this error while it works completely fine in development? Or at least a better way to debug?

**Edit:**

The real life implementation of what I'm doing here is that I have multiple pages on a site with the same layout of information, so I created a json file that is an object where each key is the route and value is the information for the route. Then I load the json and add the routes, as shown here:

```
import * as PageLayouts from '../page-layouts.json'
import { MainLayoutComponent } from './main-layout/main-layout.component'

Object.keys(PageLayouts).forEach(key => {
  mainRoutes.push({
    path: key,
    component: MainLayoutComponent
  })
})
```

I do a `console.log(mainRoutes)` after the above forEach and see all the routes in the array as expected. Also for clarification, this `forEach` loop is done before the `@NgModule` declaration, as shown in the example code. This all works totally fine with JiT compilation for development, but has the issues addressed above with AoT compilation for production.

Comment: can you try adding '/' before your route name like,  <li><a routerLink="/first">First</a></li>

Comment: Check this out [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48350889/angular-5-dynamic-route-added-but-not-routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48350889/angular-5-dynamic-route-added-but-not-routing)

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is that when you compile for production, it uses the Ahead of Time (AOT) process instead of the Just in Time (JiT) process. That is why you are seeing different results.

You can read more about AOT here: https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

And this article may be helpful: http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/08/14/ahead-of-time-compilation-angular-offline-precompilation/

Just guessing here ... but is it possible that this code is not actually executing when it is compiled with the AOT compiler?

```
mainRoutes.push({
  path: "second",
  component: SecondComponent
})
```

It does not appear to be within any Angular component or service.

Could you be more explicit about what you are trying to accomplish with this code? Are you trying to load dynamic components?

Comment: I should start by saying I should've been a little more detailed in mentioning I am aware of AOT vs JiT and knew that was why there was a difference. If I were to put a console.log of the array after calling `.push` I see all objects in the array, this is why I'm so confused as to how it's not loading into the routes. The basic explanation of what I'm doing in real life is I've got multiple pages in my site that have the same layout, so I place their content into a json file and load the routes/information from there, utilizing the same component. Will update question with an example

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(router: Router) {
    const config = router.config;
    config.push({path: 'second', component: SecondComponent});
    router.resetConfig(config);
  }
 }
```

Keep in mind that you have to add dynamic component only in entryComponents.

This code was also suggested by @mcsekar

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { RouterModule, Routes, Router } from '@angular/router'

import { AppComponent } from './app.component'
import { FirstComponent } from './first.component'
import { SecondComponent } from './second.component'

let routes: Routes = [{
  path: "first",
  component: FirstComponent
}];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FirstComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents:[SecondComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(router: Router) {
    const config = router.config;
    config.push({path: 'second', component: SecondComponent});
    router.resetConfig(config);
  }

 }
```