# Angular 5 - Dynamic Route Added but not routing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular5

I have created a new project and added some code to to the routing module for dynamic routing:

Here is the routing module code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, Router} from '@angular/router';

import { OneComponent } from './one/one.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
  constructor(router: Router, routerModule: RouterModule) {
    console.log('Routes: ', JSON.stringify(routes, undefined, 1));
    routes.push({path: 'new/random/path', component: OneComponent});
    routes.forEach((x, i) => {
      console.log(`${i}: ${JSON.stringify(x, undefined, 1)}`);
    });
  }
}
```

and the example links on app.component.html"

```
<a routerLink="home">Home</a>

<a routerLink="new/random/path">Dynamic</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The problem is that although the new route has successfully been pushed to the routes array, I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'new/random/path'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'new/random/path'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I also want to do the same, can you share the idea you have implemented here. I can see that you have mapped OneComponent  to all dynamic path. How are are you managing that much code in single Component or you are doing something else from there on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
  constructor(router: Router) {
    const config = router.config;
    config.push({path: 'new/random/path', component: OneComponent});
    router.resetConfig(config);
  }
```

Comment: The push has not been added to the routes array

Comment: I just tried this code and it worked. 

https://github.com/garapa/studying/tree/master/dynamicRoutes


The only thing that I forgot to mention is that you need to add the dynamic loaded component to the entryComponents array on the module

Comment: @LeandroLima can you share code for the same. Thanks